# Why am I automatically plundering a friendly civilization's caravan?

Tags: civilization-5

I'm playing as America in Civ V and I'm currently in the year 1884. Greece is neighboring me and we are on friendly terms. For some reason, when I click "next turn", a pop-up says that I have plundered 100 gold from one of Greece's caravans and then Alexander immediately declares war on me.

Why is this happening and what can I do to stop it? I don't want to go to war with Greece.

I'm not playing with any mods, but I do have all of the DLC if that affects anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The events are the other way around.

Greece declared war on you. Because their caravan was on top of your unit, it was automatically plundered.